# Botão para inserir novos inputs no formulário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário

Tenho um site que cadastra lançamentos de prédios. Aí alguns prédios tem mais de uma torre, e gostaria que para cada torre, eu tivesse a possibilidade de inserir 4 inputs (tipo, metragem, dormitorios, vagas)

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="torres"><button id="addtorre">Adicionar Torre</button>
<button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Aí se colocar 2 no campo "torres" e clicar em **"Adicionar Torre"**, ficaria:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="torres"><button id="addtorre">Adicionar Torre</button>
<input type="text" name="tipo1">
<input type="text" name="metragem1">
<input type="text" name="dorm1">
<input type="text" name="vaga1">
<input type="text" name="tipo2">
<input type="text" name="metragem2">
<input type="text" name="dorm2">
<input type="text" name="vaga2">
<button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazendo isso no `Jquery` você consegue adicionar:

```
$('.addtorre').click(function(){
    $('form').append(
        '<input type="text" name="tipo[]">'+
        '<input type="text" name="metragem[]">'+
        '<input type="text" name="dorm[]">'+
        '<input type="text" name="vaga[]">'
    );
});
```

Os campos se tornam arrays quando passados para o `PHP`.

> [Referência](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.html.php)

**Porque retirei o `<form>`?**

A tag `<form>` aqui só servia para representar o formulário, para não haver necessidade de criar um `preventDefault()` do formulário, a remoção da tag já faz o trabalho, uma vez que o método de envio pode ser feito em `Jquery.Ajax()`.

Aqui no `HTML` adicionei o atributo `id` às tags `<input>` e a `class="torre"`:

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="torres"><button id="addtorre">Adicionar Torre</button>
    <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
    <input type="text" name="tipo" id="1" class="torre">
    <input type="text" name="metragem" id="1" class="torre">
    <input type="text" name="dorm" id="1" class="torre">
    <input type="text" name="vaga" id="1" class="torre">
</div>
```

No `Jquery`, ao clicar no `<button>` "Adicionar Torre", é feito a busca do ultimo valor do `id`, somado 1 e então temos o `id` da torre nova, em seguida fazemos o `append()` dentro da `<div class="form">` da mesma:

```
$('#addtorre').click(function(){
    var id = parseInt($(".torre").last().attr('id'))+1;
    alert(id);
    $('.form').append(
        '<input type="text" name="tipo" id="'+id+'" class="torre">'+
        '<input type="text" name="metragem" id="'+id+'" class="torre">'+
        '<input type="text" name="dorm" id="'+id+'" class="torre">'+
        '<input type="text" name="vaga" id="'+id+'" class="torre">'
    );
});
```

Comment: legal, quase lá..rs, a única coisa é que os nome ficaram: tipo[]. E queria que a qtdade estivesse relacionada ao input "torres". ele pega o numero de torres e criar um grupo de input para cada, sabe?

Comment: mas isso ai é um array, cada torre representa uma chave

Comment: desculpa, não entendi, sou iniciante ainda

Comment: aah sim, certo, deixa eu colocar uma referencia então do que eu fiz

Comment: tira uma duvida, a torre1 ja vai existir ou é opcional tbm?

Comment: ah vdd, a 1 já existe, aí qd tiver mais de 1 torre vai adicionando mais

Comment: editei a resposta, qualquer coisa só avisar

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!!